# How to convert data from authorization tab to code in Postman OAuth2 authorization

Tags: c#, postman

I need to do OAuth2 authorization and I made it in Postman in authorization tab but how this request convert to code, for example C#?
Because Postman is allow convert request with all headers and param to code in separate tab
But datas from authorization tab don't allow. Please somebody ara describe how to convert all data from this tab to code
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The authorisation code flow is not as trivial as just one request. It is multiple requests following a very specific format.

I would suggest you look into it here: https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow

There are also guides to create your own login page from within .net and .net core:https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp